# Parsing a JSON string and store in a variable

Tags: python, json, api

Hi Guys I am calling this API to see the live data of a price from Coingecko, I am trying to parse the json file but keep getting a error in my code when i use json.loads. I imported json and still get this error

Here is a snippet of my code

```
import json
import requests

class LivePrice(object):   #Coingecko API
    def GetPrice(self, coin):
        coinprice = coin
        Gecko_endpoint = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids='
        currency  = '&vs_currencies=usd'
        url = Gecko_endpoint + coinprice + currency
        r = requests.get(url, headers = {'accept': 'application/json'})
        y = json.loads(r)  
        #print(r.json()[coinprice]['usd'])
```

if I use this print function i get the price but I want to be able to use the variable and pass it to another class to do some calculation

Just trying to make a simple trading bot for fun while using Alpaca API for paper trading

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "AlapacaBot.py", line 76, in <module>
     r.GetPrice(Bitcoin)
    File "AlapacaBot.py", line 65, in GetPrice
     y = json.loads(r)  
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 341, in loads
     raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response
```

I am following the example from w3schools but I keep getting an error
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

Comment: `requests.get()` returns a `Response` object. Call `text()` on it to get the response body as a `str`. More simply, you can call `json()` to parse it directly without having to import `json` separately.

Comment: "I am following the example from w3schools but I keep getting an error" no you aren't. Why are you passing the `Response` object to `json.load`? For starters, you can just use `result = r.json()`. You could do `json.load(r.text)`, although that is basically the same as `r.json()`

Comment: Don't forget to check `r.status_code` to make sure the request succeeded (200 is normal "good").

Answer (score 0):

`json.loads` only accepts the types listed in your error.

`requests` get method returns a `Response` object, not one of those types. The W3Schools link is not a replacement for the Python Requests module documentation, as it only shows strings, not `Response` objects.

Response objects have a `json()` function to get the body as a dictionary, which you commented out

```
r = requests.get(url, headers = {'accept': 'application/json'})
y = r.json()
print(y[coin]['usd'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. You only need to use the requests.json() to retrieve the json information

```
import json
import requests

class LivePrice:   #Coingecko API
    def GetPrice(coin):
        coinprice = coin
        Gecko_endpoint = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids='
        currency  = '&vs_currencies=usd'
        url = Gecko_endpoint + coinprice + currency
        r = requests.get(url, headers = {'accept': 'application/json'})
        y = r.json()  
        print(y[coinprice]['usd']) 
LivePrice.GetPrice("bitcoin")
```